# Typescript: map object value type for each key

Tags: typescript

In the example code bellow:

```
const obj = {
  a: () => 1,
  b: () => '2'
}

type typeMap = Record<keyof typeof obj, (arg: unknown) => void>

const map: typeMap = {
  a: (numberArg) => numberArg + 1,
  b: (stringArg) => stringArg.length
}
```

I want Typescript to be aware of the function arguments types in the `map` object to be the same as the return type of each key in the original `obj` object. I know there is the `ReturnType<>` utility, but I don't know how to use it to map each prop from `obj`.

In summary, I want `numberArg` to be of type `number` and `stringArg` to be of type `string`.

You can open this code in [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDGBDAXDABQCUqAfDAIwA02M8hpFMA5AEyuYC+mmUATwAOAUxiDRAWVxDUMAEojQAJwAmAHgDWIgSABm44SP1wkNYrmUBzQgFcwmsCADuYMikoA3EAEtV5PlBIWABbGUIJEWlZNCwcAmIwWxD4EWUAQWt3SiSUtMyrGABqajocRmJoZR8wKwLsmCqauusAOgAbEVqoAAseIA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [mapped object type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types):

```
// alias for convenience
type ObjType = typeof obj;
type TypeMap = {
  [K in keyof ObjType]: (arg: ReturnType<ObjType[K]>) => unknown
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDGBDAXDABQCUqAfDAIwA02M8hpFMA5AEyuYC+mmA9PzwAbAJa4IMAGYgATjFBgAbgFMwotcBWYoATwAOKmAHkkAFQNG0ewyClwkAbh2WYFwwFlc+1BnoBtAGkYUTAYAGsVXTsTc0sAXSZcWQBzQgAlFSgAV1kwdxUAHlNEAqD48jIUSmywcLAQAHcwHmdMRWgYAFtvQgKvHzQsHAJiMGyu+BVZAEFUqspxyem5lJgAamo6HEZiaFlQlNWFmH3D1YA6YTUUqAALVswgA)

Comment: awesome! that worked, thank you very much for the fast answer

Comment: @Oswaldo I'm glad I could help you! If you're satisfied, please [mark the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so people know that the question's been answered.

Comment: Is there a solution that properly handles the type conversion for values? This solution loses information by setting the type for each mapped field to unknown.